# Конструктор на Java

Tags: java

У меня есть некие устройства, к которым можно подключаться по SSH - Device1 и Telnet - Device2, оба наследуются от класса Device. Есть класс Connection. В классе Connection есть два конструктора, которые принимают Device1 или Device2 соответственно. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы все мои устройства Device1 и Device2 (каждого вида может быть по несколько штук) положить в какую нибудь коллекцию типа Device, а потом через цикл передавать все мои устройства в Connection не приводя к типу?

По отдельности у меня всё получается, а вот вместе чет не выходит пока. Как поступить лучше в данной ситуации?

Вот пример:

```
package devices;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Device> devices = new ArrayList<Device>();
        devices.add(new Device1("device1", "127.0.0.1"));
        devices.add(new Device2("username", "password"));

        for (int i = 0; i < devices.size(); i++) {
            TestSender sender = new TestSender(devices.get(i)); //так не работает
            TestSender sender1 = new TestSender((Device1) devices.get(i)); //так работает
            TestSender sender2 = new TestSender((Device2) devices.get(i)); //так работает
        }
    }
}

class TestSender {
    public TestSender(Device1 device1) {
        String s = device1.getName() + " " + device1.getHost();
        run(s);
    }

    public TestSender(Device2 device2) {
        String s = device2.getUsername() + " " + device2.getPassword();
        run(s);
    }

    public void run(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Comment: создайте для них общий интерфейс имплементируйте к нему оба класса и помещайте в коллекцию по типу интерфейса, а не класса, но чтобы это работало без приведения к типу, они должны использовать одинаковые методы (имена)

Comment: А если для каждого устройства определены методы в интерфейсе, которые различаются?

Comment: если у каждого класса есть уникальные методы, то без приведения к типу не обойтись, в интерфейсе же не может быть различающихся методов для классов, его реализующих. классы могут иметь дополнительные методы, не объявленные в интерфейсе

Comment: Кажется теперь понимаю, что нужно общие методы написать в интерфейса, а уникальные у каждого класса. Буду пробовать!

Comment: Получается всё-равно не могу передать в TestSender объект типа Device. Подскажи на примере как его туда можно добавить.