# Помочь разобрать с Конструктором

Tags: java

Как можно вызвать нужный конструктор у класса Sender, когда мы не знаем какой именно передаем Device через цикл?

```
package devices;

import java.util.ArrayList;

abstract class Device {
    String name;
    String host;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }
}
class Device1 extends Device {
    Device1 (String name, String host){
        this.name = name;
        this.host = host;
    }
}
class Device2 extends Device {
    Device2 (String name, String host){
        this.name = name;
        this.host = host;
    }
}
class Sender {
    public Sender(Device1 device1) {
        connectSSH(device1.getName(), device1.getHost());
    }
    public Sender(Device2 device2) {
        connectTelnet(device1.getName(), device1.getHost());
    }
    void connectSSH(String name, String host){
        тут выполняется коннект по протоколу SSH;
    }
    void connectTelnet(String name, String host){
        тут выполняется коннект по протоколу Telnet;
    }

}
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Device> devices = new ArrayList<Device>();
        devices.add(new Device1("Device1", "PC100"));
        devices.add(new Device2("Device2", "PC200"));
        for (int i = 0; i < devices.size(); i++) {
            Sender sender = new Sender(devices.get(i));//Не создаёт объект Serndr без приведения типов
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: я же вам говорил в [прошлом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1019838/177345) - имплементация интерфейса (а не наследование) и использовать тип интерфейса. и не нужно задавать почти одинаковые вопросы, это не поможет получить ответ быстрее

Comment: Да, с дублирующим вопросом - согласен, но я переспросил в прошлом вопросе и ответа не получил. 
Хотел попросить показать пример, как можно это реализовать

Comment: мало на какие вопросы отвечают сразу же, нужно подождать. у меня, к примеру сейчас нет возможности печатать код. реализуете методы в интерфейсе по типу getParameter1(), getParameter2() и тд. в классах реализуете логику получения конкретных параметров. при извлечении получаете их. проблема тут в том, что нельзя понять, какой именно, например, параметр2 получен (адрес хоста или пароль из прошлого вопроса) - нужно или как то писать логику определения или делать приведение к конкретному типу класса

Comment: и у вас принципиальная разница с прошлым вопросом. здесь устройство1 и устройство2 получает одинаковые параметры, в прошлом вопросе разные - именно в этом у вас и проблема с типами в начальном вопросе. в этом вопросе вообще не нужны ни наследования ни интерфейсы, классы идентичны

Comment: @pavlofff device1 и device2 - это абсолютно разные два устройства, у каждого из них своя логика, а параметры я привел для примера.
класс sender умеет работать с любым из устройств, которые хранятся за пределами класса. Имеется коллекция с типом Device, в которой хранятся разные устройства - по этому они и наследуются(насколько я понимаю). 
а класс sender в зависимости принятого устройства - выполняет логику А или логику Б.

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка в архитектуре. Вам нужно в класс `Sender` передавать объект класса `Device`. А какой именно - сендеру все равно.

Если для конкретного класса нужно производить какие-то специфические действия, до эти действия имеет смысл вынести в сам класс

```
abstract class Device {
    private final String name;
    private final String host;

    Device(String name, String host){
        this.name = name;
        this.host = host;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public abstract void connect();
}

class Device1 extends Device {
    Device1 (String name, String host){
        super(name, host);
    }
    @Override
    public void connect() {
      // connect to SSH
    }
}

class Device2 extends Device {
    Device2 (String name, String host){
        super(name, host);
    }
    @Override
    public void connect() {
      // connect to Telnet
    }
}

class Sender {
    public Sender(Device device) {
        device.connect());
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Device> devices = new ArrayList<Device>();
        devices.add(new Device1("Device1", "PC100"));
        devices.add(new Device2("Device2", "PC200"));
        for (int i = 0; i < devices.size(); i++) {
            Sender sender = new Sender(devices.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Получается по вашему примеру класс Sender только принимает Device, а я бы хотел иметь два конструктора и в зависимости от устройства выполнять разные методы в классе Sender

Comment: @ВасилийПавлов В вашем коде я не вижу разных методов. Обновите вопрос и приведите пример разных методов.

Comment: Антон, смотрите [прошлый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1019838/177345), там понятно в чем именно проблема

Comment: @AntonShchyrov обновил пример кода

Comment: @ВасилийПавлов Обновил ответ